# metro bootstrap div box in one line

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

hey guys im tring to build a Website in Metro look and im working with the Metro UI CSS 2.0 css.

i just start right now and i have a lil Problem. i would like to have 3 div boxes under each other. but i just get them in one line. if i give the row div a width of 125px are they under each other , but i dont think that this is the clean way .

could ya help me out please.

here is the link to my site where it is. [demo site](http://hoojoo.awesom-media.de)

```
 <div class="grid">
 <div class="row" style="width:125px">
   <div class="tile "></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile selected"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: wrap each in a div class="row"

Comment: Either use Dan's suggestion, or nest your grid. Same difference.

Comment: yes, but than is the space between each div to much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <div class="grid">
      <div class="row my-width">
         <div class="tile "></div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="tile"></div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="tile selected"></div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-width {
   width: 125px;
}
```

Comment: ah , perfect.  but i dont have to put every tile box in a row -my width or do i have to ? cause all tile in one my-width has also the effect that i whant or does it have a Special reasion why u put each div in a custom my width

Comment: Fix it. the grid must be 100% cause there is more Content coming is this one. the row div must has the my-width Attribute with 125px

<div class="grid">
      <div class="row  my-width">
         <div class="tile "></div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="tile"></div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="tile selected"></div>
       </div>
 </div>